# How to select array of Integers in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I want to select from the table arrays of integers like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now in trying something like this:

```
(SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(s))) FROM(
 SELECT specialty FROM talent_specialty WHERE userid = 840 )s);
```

and this is the record that query is returning

```
[{"specialty":1},{"specialty":2}]
```

Table look like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Tony just array of integers like this  [1, 2, 3]

Comment: So just to make sure i understood. You have `[{"specialty":1},{"specialty":2}, ...]` and want `[1,2,3,...]`?

Comment: @Tony Yes I want to write the query that will return a result like this: [1,2,3,...]

Comment: [{"specialty":1},{"specialty":2}, ...] is the value from your table? Or does your table contain columns with rows 1,2,3? It would be nice if you could add a sample table to your question

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).. (no images for example data we can't work with those)

Comment: @S-Man I added how my table look in question

Comment: OK, what about my answer? Doesn't it help?

Comment: how do you expect the JSON array `[1, 2, 3]` as result there isn't specialty with 3 for the user 840?

Comment: @S-Man I need to return JSON array

Comment: Yes this is what json_agg does (see linked demo and documentation)

Comment: Edin Puzic @S-Man 's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply search for [`json_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)?

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a486270bda4bb8f12e0353fb28cdb0df)

```
SELECT json_agg(speciality) 
FROM talent_speciality
```

---

If you are not needing a JSON array but a simple array you could use `array_agg` of course

```
SELECT array_agg(speciality) 
FROM talent_speciality
```